# security issues and thoughts reading an rss feed

Tags: ios, iphone, security, rss

I'm working on an app that is reading it's data from a customized RSS feed, that contains information about events. The feed is parsed with the GData XML framework, and written to SQLite with the FMDB wrapper.

The feed information is created on the server by a web-app.

I'm now thinking about how I can make the app bullet proof against hacking attacks that might get through the servers validation. I have seen some threads here about SQL Injection, so I have information regarding that.

Are there other attacks/mechanisms to consider?

The information in my feed is not secret, I'm only after a well working app that can not be hacked easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[late answer]

You should harden your server. There is not much you can do to secure the feed itself against man in the middle unfortunately, as SSL and/or XML signature is not really defined for RSS.